# Asynchronous tasks with react hooks - Going crazy trying to understand

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm a newbie as a dev and would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

- on mounting -> grab the data either from a context file ( if the parameters passed off to the route are a number) or from an api ( if the parameters are a string)
- as soon as 'the data is ready'  formate it
- feed it to the child components

main pb:     my  'dataInUse' always remain 'null' when being passed off to the formating function
don't know if it is a 'closure thing'????   the setDataInUse which is asynchronous  ?? a render which triggers and reset datainuse to null or ... something  else all together different ...
I'm completely lost.

Up until now I've been browsing though the doc, pulling every possible articles dealing of the topic off the web, breaking my code but I can't figure out what is happening. The code is hella messy but I v been trying a lot of things and I ain't that good to begin with so sorry for the large 'dump' I'm gracing your eyes with.

Here is the snippet:

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import Grid from './grid';
import SearchedWord from './searchedWords';
import NotifPartyWon from './NotifPartyWon';
import Rules from './rules';

import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

import {WordContext} from '../contexts/wordContext';
import {GridContext} from '../contexts/gridContext';

//=========================================================

const Game = ({match})=>{


    useEffect(()=>{console.log('render use effect no []')})

    console.log('GAMEEEE   RENDERING')
    let params = match.params.id;
    const apiPath= "https://api.datamuse.com/words?";

    const { words:{sets} }= useContext(WordContext);
    const themes = useContext(GridContext);

    //let [dataReady, setDataReady]= useState(false)

    let [dataInUse, setDataInUse]= useState(null)


    let [partyWon, setPartyWon]= useState(false)


    let [userSelect, setUserSelect]= useState([]);
        useEffect(()=>{setPartyWon(false); },[params]);

    let finalThemeData= [{name:''}]

    //let [finalThemeData, setFinalThemeData]= useState([{name:''}])
    //let finalThemeDataRef= useRef(finalThemeData)
    //finalThemeDataRef.current= finalThemeData

    let finalWorldsData= []

    //let [finalWorldsData, setFinalWorldsData] = useState([])
    //let finalWorldsDataRef= useRef(finalWorldsData)
    //finalWorldsDataRef.current = finalWorldsData
    let shortenedArray=null

/*  let [clickBtwTimeOut, setClickBtwTimeOut]= useState(1)
let countRef= useRef(clickBtwTimeOut)
countRef.current= clickBtwTimeOut
*/

//////////////////////
    let manipArray=()=>{
        console.log('mainparray fired ' + JSON.stringify(dataInUse))

        var LessThan10LettersWords = dataInUse[0].words.wordsAssociated.filter(word=> word.orthograph.length < 10)

        //sortArray so that longer words go first -> less pb
        
        var sortedMax10LettersWords =LessThan10LettersWords.sort(function(a, b){
 
                return b.orthograph.length - a.orthograph.length;
            });

        shortenedArray=(sortedMax10LettersWords.slice(0,4).concat(sortedMax10LettersWords.slice(-4)))
    }
//////////////////////
///--------------------

    let getDataFromApproriateSource = async()=>{

    
        if(Number.isInteger(parseInt(params))){

//isolate exact set of words we want
            console.log( 'if ')

            finalThemeData = themes.filter(theme=> theme.id === params)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(finalThemeData))
            finalWorldsData = sets.filter(set=> set.id === params)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(finalWorldsData))
            setDataInUse( dataInUse=>{dataInUse[0].theme= finalThemeData[0]; dataInUse[0].words= finalWorldsData}, manipArray())
          // setDataInUse([{theme:{...finalThemeData[0]}, words:[...finalWorldsData]}], manipArray())

            //manipArray()
            

        }else{

            console.log( 'else ' )

    
            async function getData(){
                console.log( apiPath + "rel_trg=" + params);
                await fetch(apiPath + "rel_trg=" + params)
                    .then(res => res.json() )
                    .then(data=>{
                        //console.log('the data '+data);
                        let tempData =[{ id: null, wordsAssociated: [] }];
                        //console.log('BOYA ' + JSON.stringify(finalWorldsData))
                        data.map(apiHit=>{
                            tempData[0].wordsAssociated.push({orthograph: apiHit.word, successfullyFound: false})
                        });
                    //  console.log('tempData ' + tempData)
                        finalThemeData=[{id: null, name:params, associatedSetOfWords: null}]

                        finalWorldsData=[...tempData]

                    //setDataReady(true);
                    //setSetOfWordsInUse(formatedData)  
                    console.log('rr '+ JSON.stringify(finalThemeData) +JSON.stringify(finalWorldsData))
                    //setDataInUse([{theme:{...finalThemeData[0]}, words:[...finalWorldsData]}], manipArray())


                    
                })
                
            }
        await getData()
        //setDataInUse([{theme:{...finalThemeData[0]}, words:[...finalWorldsData]}], manipArray())
        console.log('CHECK' + JSON.stringify(finalThemeData))
        setDataInUse([{theme:{...finalThemeData[0]}, words:[...finalWorldsData]}], manipArray())

    }


}

    useEffect( ()=>{
    console.log('effect when mounted ');
    getDataFromApproriateSource();
    console.log('end effect when mounted ' + dataInUse);

    },[])

    useEffect( ()=>{
        console.log('effect when dataInUse ' + dataInUse);

        if(dataInUse !== null){
            console.log('datinuse not null')
            shortenedArray = dataInUse
        }
    },[dataInUse])

let displayTheme = ()=>{
        //console.log('inside displaytheme' + JSON.stringify(finalThemeData) + JSON.stringify(finalWorldsData))
        console.log('inside displaytheme' + JSON.stringify(dataInUse) )
        return(<h1 id='gameTitle'>{dataInUse[0].theme.name}  </h1>)
    };

    let displayui = ()=>{
                console.log('inside displayui' )

        return(
            <div id='gameandRule'>
                <div id='gameUI'>
                    <Grid params={params} userSelect={userSelect} setUserSelect={setUserSelect} shortenedArray={shortenedArray} setId={params} setPartyWon={setPartyWon} partyWon={partyWon} />
                    <SearchedWord shortenedArray={shortenedArray} />
                    {partyWon && <NotifPartyWon />}
                </div>
                <Rules/>
            </div>
            )
    };


    return(
        
        <div >
            <div id='gamePageTop'>
            {dataInUse !== null && displayTheme()
            }
                <div>
                    <a href='#rules'>i</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='gamePageAction'>
                <p>Get to know them all...</p> 
                
                <Link to={`/grid/${parseInt(params)+1}`} className={`gameLink ${parseInt(params) +1 > themes.length?'noVisible':''}` } >Next game</Link>
            </div>
            {dataInUse !== null && displayui()
            }

        </div>


        )
};

export default Game;
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Setter functions do not take a second argument, so when you call `setDataInUse`, the `manipArray` function will not be called.

Comment: Also, I recommend you use a code formatter like Prettier, because it looks like you're manually formatting your code and it's quite hard to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot, JMadelaine !  It helped me a great deal. I'll definitely look into Prettier too ^^